# using runat="server" gives Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

**Javascript**

```
var form = document.getElementById('date_budget');
pop('', 'exp_upd', '95', '80');
form.action = "test.aspx";
form.target = 'exp_upd';
form.submit();
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="date_budget" name="date_budget" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <!--#include file="zone.inc" -->
        <td id='mlodg_loc'><select name="loc" id="loc">
                <option value="Select Location">Select Location</option>
            </select></td>
        <td>
            <select name="month" id="month">    
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="year" id="year">
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The above code opens a popup window, but when I change the html by adding the runat attribute, I am getting “Validation of viewstate MAC failed”, and some extra junk. the modified html is below

```
<form id="date_budget" name="date_budget" method="post" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <!--#include file="zone.inc" -->
        <td id='mlodg_loc'><select name="loc" id="loc" runat="server">
            <option value="Select Location">Select Location</option>
            </select></td>
            <td>
                <select name="month" id="month" runat="server"> 
                <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="year" id="year" runat="server">
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Is there any workaround to use both the runat server and using the same element in JS, without using those asp tags something like `<%= hidBT.ClientID %>` I don't want that any other way.

Comment: I can't see any difference in your two html blocks of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to add this `<pages enableViewStateMac="false">` in your **web.config** (or)
2. Try to Change this  `<form id="date_budget" name="date_budget" method="post">` to

   this  `<form id="date_budget" name="date_budget" runat="server">`

   **It shouldn't specify method or action**

Comment: I tried with the first one but of no use, and second one too.

Comment: added <pages enableViewStateMac="false"></pages> in <system.web>, it worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the ClientIDMode="Static" on the control or in the @Page directive. That will keep the id of the form as "date_budget".

Otherwise if you don't need the ViewState on the page, then you can disable it in the @Page directive using EnableViewState="false".

Comment: none of the solution is working, I mean same problem if i use runat server, followed the below answers also